# Sending alert to pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on web application , in my project there is some type of testing and task assignment to employees.

Now when an employee complete a task and assigned to a user the user automatically get the message on his page ( there is 3 user accessing application , one is admin , second is tester and third is verifier ...both of them works on different pages , now when admin assign a task the tester automatically get a notification " new message " ( for this i am using master page)..on whatever page the tester is on working... now if the tester is completes it 's task and assign to verifier , verifier must get notification "new message" ... and so on..)

for this a have put a button on master page ..and also i have make a windows service that runs on every minute , now my problem is how i sent the message from windows service to my master page button ( that i change text of button).

Is this idea working ?

Comment: You could read about Ajax and Web Methods with ASP.NET and jQuery. You can then call directly the method with an ajax request. The method will return you some value, and you will operate with this value through Java Script, assigning it where you want it. (All this combined with some timer, I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to window service to run in background? Is there any specific reason to have the windows service for these requirements?

As per your detailed description what I understood is that when the employee completes a task and assigned to a user the user automatically get the message on his page. So when the employee is working and completed means they will click on some button that their work is completed. Then while clicking on the button, you just write the code for sending the mail to the tester. like the same way, when the tester is completed their work and click on the testing completes, send a mail to the reviewer and so on..Then where is the need to have a window service for this to send the mails?

All the requirements can be achieved through the simple send mail code.
Let us know if you need any more help or if you don't understand the exact scenario or if anything is missing in the requirements.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to send from a windows service informations to asp.page. You can create a button that can query a webservice about new tasks (but you are counting on the user to press it).

Another more "friendly" way is to have a timer in javascript that uses ajax requests to get new tasks.